# Grails Filters vs Interceptor

Tags: grails

I have been studying Grails for quite a while now. And scanned a little bit about Filters and Interceptors. Both have almost the same functionality of tracking the sessions or redirecting unauthorized users in a particular controller.

But I'm confused when and why should I use Filter than Interceptor and vice versa.
Given that the Inceptors have two controller methods `beforeInterceptor` and `afterInterceptor` and for the Filters a three common closures `before`, `after` and `afterView`.

My questions is what are the pros and cons of using Filter against Interceptor or vise versa. In this manner we, developers, can decide when, where, and why we should use either Filter or Interceptor in a particular Controller to do some tracking, redirect, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use one or both interceptors in a controller when the interception logic only applies to that controller.

Use a filter when the logic applies to multiple (or all) controllers, or when you need to do something after the view is rendered (there's no interceptor equivalent of afterView), or if you just want to keep everything centralized in one place instead of spread across separate controller files.

Comment: I see. But isn't you can create a Abstract Controller to hold similar interception logic and let this controller be the parent of all of the other controllers?

At what instance can we say we need to have the filterering logic declared by `Filters` in the its closure, `afterView`?

Comment: And then you'll need a bit differ logic, so need to create another abstract controller. Filters can help you to concentrate code in one place and skip dependencies you don't really need.

Answer (score 2):

The Old Filters (From Grails 2) are deprecated in Grails 3. The replacement to the Filters are Interceptors.

The use of interceptors is for actions such as: authentication, loggin, etc.  
The interceptors (as their name implies) are intercepting the incoming web requests and trigger a related actions. The actions are defined in the related Controller.

The Interceptors have some major benefits (over the Filters) such as support for static compilation, and enable flexible configurations.  
These are the main 3 methods of the Interceptor: 
- *boolean before() { true }* 
- *boolean after() { true }* 
- *void afterView() { }*

The Iterceptors are configured as Spring Beans (in the Spring application context) and are configured to be auto-wired by their names.